# NestJS - [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying ER_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Cannot able to connect database with correct connection info, followed documentation to connect database from https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

**Database connected on SQLYog**

[image]

Following same database information in **app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: null,
      database: 'the_local_db',
      entities: [
        Table_one,
      ],
      // entities: ['../typeorm/entities/*.ts'],

      synchronize: true,
    }),
    StaffModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Error Details

`[Nest] 5528   - 06/30/2020, 1:39:51 AM   [ExceptionHandler] ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''"'' at line 1 +18m
QueryFailedError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''"'' at line 1

at new QueryFailedError (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\src\error\QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
at Query. (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:167:37)
at Query. (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:92:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\UserName\ProjectName\nrwl\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)`

Comment: You should include the code of your Table_one entity. PS. In the title you mention a different error than in the question text.

Comment: Table_one entity already imported at top of file, but not shown here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just removed the port:3306, now it's working.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      username: 'root',
      password: null,
      database: 'the_local_db',
      entities: [
        Table_one,
      ],
      // entities: ['../typeorm/entities/*.ts'],

      synchronize: true,
    }),
    StaffModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 18):

Check if you have synchronize connection option set to true in database configuration. Make it to false.
It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, it worked for me. But if I need to run in synchronized mode I've to set it to true right? 
For that is there any ways or work arounds?

Comment: @Vaddadi  if it is set to true - it might be for a reason. like in my case

Comment: It was the problem in my case too, thank you @Vaddadi

Answer (score 9):

I was faced with a similar issue and the verified response did not help me. I was able to solve my issue using the `mysql2` module instead of `mysql`.

```
$ npm install mysql2 --save
```

I also had to uninstall `mysql` module to connect to my database

```
$ npm uninstall mysql --save
```

Hope this response helped others with stuck in the same issue.

Comment: The important part is  uninstall mysql.
Great answer.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the solution was some different because my localhost had a different name,it happened in OSX sometimes,so I changed the "localhost" by the ip adress 127.0.0.1

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'test',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'nest',
  entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema:true })
```

Comment: Context on why this could be the reason: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1624#issuecomment-1233424362

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using a connection URL instead of splitting the MongoDB URI.

```
dbConfig: {
    type: 'mongodb',
    url: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING,
    ssl: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
}
```

Where `MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: mongodb://ussername:password@host_name:port/?authSource=admin`
. This way one can avoid getting this error in TypeORM. Also, there is a flag **`useNewUrlParser: true`** which could be used to configure DB in a way using the host `username` and `password` separately.

Answer (score 0):

First, i solved my problem by using as following:
1/ synchronize :false in the app.module
2/nmp uninstall mysql
3/npm install mysql2
--> when i run >>npm run start:dev everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

did you start your  XAMP mysql server on locally? because i was not (:

just reminder

Answer (score 0):

I sovled it by changing host with `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.
Beacase in the `ipv6`, the `localhost` will be transformed to `::1` but no `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
```

api         | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.80.2:3306

When occurs this error this I change the docker-compose file volume name

```
version: "3"
```

services:
api:
build:
context: ../
dockerfile: ./docker/files/dev.Dockerfile
container_name: "api"
env_file:
- ./env/api.env
depends_on:
- database
ports:
- "3000:3000"
volumes:
- /usr/src/app/node_modules
- ../app/:/usr/src/app/
working_dir: /usr/src/app
command: ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

database:
image: mysql:8
restart: unless-stopped
container_name: database
env_file:
- ./env/db.env
volumes:
- db1:/var/lib/mysql   //Provious db  (change 1)
ports:
- "3307:3306"

volumes:
db1: //Provious db (change 2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if I use synchronize connection : false, it works for me. But I find a column added in a table with nullable is false, so some old entities don't have data. I change new column nullable is true and it works with synchronize: true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> [Nest] 126688  - 02/21/2024, 9:44:38 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...

Check the database **username**, and **password**.